# Using Python on C/C++/Java API?

Tags: api, python-3.x

There are APIs for C, APIs for C++, APIs for Java, APIs for Python, etc.
Is it possible to use Python on APIs built for C/C++/Java?

Comment: Yes, and yes http://www.jython.org/, https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: I mean, using Python without any extension. Just pure Python + some creativity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) for call functions directly from C/C++ API.
But if you need to call java functions, you need external python modules as [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) or [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).